# how to give quick replies (Dialogflow) using spring java?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to respond with quick replies to webhookrequest(Dialogflow) using java spring. I had create a chatbot for Slack using Dialogflow. I want to add content as response which is **dynamic** which means I cant always go and add the content manually through Dialoglfow console. So I thought of using quick replies but how should I implement it with java spring?

I want it in this way:

U: what is the total cost

Bot: For which account:

```
 1. ABC
 2. PQR
 3. XYZ
```

U: clicks option 1 ABC

Bot: Total cost for ABC is xxx

Comment: for this you need to use webhook and based on intent you can call the fulfillment API like cost one in your example.

Comment: I am already using webhook and check the intent and then make an API call but how can I send rich responses (quick replies) using spring